# Opening files with wstring path in MinGW

Tags: c++, boost, mingw, fstream

I'm using [library for parsing Standard MIDI Files](https://midifile.sapp.org/) which allows you to read files in 2 ways:

```cpp
    bool MidiFile::read(const std::string& filename) {/* --- */}
    //and
    bool MidiFile::read(std::istream& input) {/* --- */}
```

To open midi files with wstring path in MSVC, I could just do like this:

```cpp
    MidiFile *mf = new MidiFile();
    fstream input;
    input.open(L"Файл.mid", ios::binary | ios::in);
    mf->read(input);
    input.close();
```

But it seems that GCC doesn't have overload of the `fstream::open` method for `wstring` type like in MSVC. How I can open files with wsting path in MinGW and use it to pass to the Midifile libriary? Or is there a way to open file in C style or with other libriary and somehow convert the data from file to `std::istream`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a C++17 feature. Make sure your compiler is new enough, and that you're building with at least `-std=c++17`.

Note that it will only compile if `std::filesystem::path::value_type` is `wchar_t`, in other words - only on Windows. To make the code portable, convert the path to `std::filesystem::path` first.

Answer (score 0):

I found an acceptable solution albeit slower:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "craigsapp-midifile/MidiFile.h"

int main()
{
    FILE* fp;
    _wfopen_s(&fp, L"МИДИ.mid", L"rb");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    std::string str(fsize, '*');

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) 
        str[i] = (char)getc(fp);
    fclose(fp);

    std::stringstream binarydata;
    binarydata << str;

    smf::MidiFile mf;
    if (mf.read(binarydata)) 
        std::cout << "midi read success!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```